# ReactNative: Cancelling subscriptions from within app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, in-app-billing, react-native-in-app-utils

I'm building a react-native app with subscriptions. I understand that subscriptions can be cancelled via `Settings` on `iOS` and `My Apps` section on the `Play Store`.

Is there a way to add a link to these sections within the app itself?

I found this link for iOS but can't test it yet as my application isn't live.
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions

PS. I'm using `react-native-in-app-utils` and `react-native-billing`

Comment: On iOS you open that URL, which will take the user out of your app and into the iTunes app in order to manage their subscriptions